# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. After deployment to cloud

Tags: python, django, forms, csrf-token

I wrote a Django application and after I developed it to put it into a Docker container and deploy it to Google Cloud Run. The server is OK and running but when I want to type something in the forms and submit it I got this error:

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

What's the problem with it? Should I add something besides the csrf_token?

Here's my views.py:

```python
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . models import Action
##from django.core.mail import send_email

def index (request):
    actions = Action.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"actions": actions})

def uj_szemely (request):
    
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render(request, 'uj_szemely.html')
    elif request.method == "POST":
        surname = request.POST.get('surname')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname')
        whatdo = request.POST.get('whatdo')
        done = request.POST.get('done')
        created = request.POST.get('created')
        deadline = request.POST.get('deadline')
        
        if done == 'on':
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
            
        formaction = Action(surname=surname, lastname=lastname, whatdo=whatdo, done=done, created=created, deadline=deadline)
        formaction.save()
        
        return redirect('fooldal')
    

def fooldal (request):
    return render(request, 'fooldal.html')
```

My models.py:

```python
from pyexpat import model
from django.db import models

class Action (models.Model):
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    whatdo = models.TextField()
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    deadline = models.DateTimeField()
```

I also have a contact page on the website and the contact form is giving the same error.
Here is my contact forms module:

```python
from logging import PlaceHolder
from django import forms

temak = [('egyéb', 'Egyéb'), ('reklamáció', 'Reklamáció'),('megkeresés', 'Megkeresés'), ('tájékoztatás', 'Tájékoztatás')]

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    nev = forms.CharField(max_length=50, label="Név", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Írja be a nevét!'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Írja be az e-mail címét!'}))
    tema = forms.ChoiceField(choices=temak, label="Téma")
    uzenet = forms.CharField(label="Üzenet", widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Írjon nekünk...'}))
```

And my contact's views.py:

```python
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

def kapcsolat (request):
    form = ContactForm()
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            nev = form.cleaned_data['nev']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            tema = form.cleaned_data['tema']
            uzenet = form.cleaned_data['uzenet']
            
            email_to_send = EmailMessage (
                subject=tema,
                body=uzenet,
                from_email=email,
                to=['dezsoszabolcs46@gmail.com'],
                reply_to=[email],
                headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
            )
            
            email_to_send.send()
            
            return render(request, 'kapcsolat_valasz.html', {'nev':nev, 'tema':tema})
        
        
    return render(request, 'kapcsolat.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, This seem to be related to ALLOWED_HOSTS or CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS but no idea how to fix it. https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django#5. Here some value are being applied but do not know what they are as they are env variable, hope you might find fix, please reply if you find it. Edit: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#csrf_configurations Here is the issue i think.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `{% csrf_token %}` inside your form? please share your form code.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/run#csrf_configurations . This is the issue but idk what are the values since values are environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Need to add CSRF Trusted Origin to the settings.py

###### SECURITY WARNING: It's recommended that you use this when

###### running in production. The URL will be known once you first deploy

###### to Cloud Run. This code takes the URL and converts it to both these settings formats.

````
if CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = [urlparse(CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL).netloc]
    CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [CLOUDRUN_SERVICE_URL]
    SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
    SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
else:
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]```
````